# How to shift >= 32 bits in uint64_t?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

The following code triggers a `gcc` warning (gcc 4.2.1):

```
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
boost::uint64_t x = 1 << 32; // warning: left shift count >= width of type
```

Shouldn't it be fine since the type has 64 bits?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> > *How to shift >= 32 bits in `uint64_t`?*

If your compiler supports `long long`:

```
boost::uint64_t x = 1LL << 32;
```

Otherwise:

```
boost::uint64_t x = boost::uint64_t(1) << 32;
```

> > *Shouldn't it be fine since the type has 64 bits?*

No. Even though `x` is 64 bits, `1` isn't. `1` is 32 bits. How you use a result has no effect on how that result is generated.

Comment: This is a frequent misunderstanding of how types work in C++. How you *use* a result has no effect on how that result is generated. `1 << 32` is `1 << 32`. If you have `int foo(int);` and `double foo(double);`, if you do `double bar = foo(1);`, the fact that you stored the result in a double doesn't affect which `foo` gets called.

Comment: Or: `uint64_t x = 1; x <<= 32;`